# Can't change spring webflow state if jsf client side validation fails

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-webflow, client-side-validation

I have a simple form for creating a record - it has some fields which are required and two buttons, one for submit and one for cancel. The problem is that cancel button is not working (it actually always reloads the view for creating record), unless all required fields are entered.
Field looks like this

```
<h:inputText id="name"
    value="#{userController.User.name}"
    required="true"
    requiredMessage="This field is required"
    maxlength="11" tabindex="22" />
```

In spring webflow definition i added validation="false", also tried binding="false", but it didn't help, although I'm not sure if it is relevant, as I have problem with jsf validation, not spring webflow validation.
Also to add that I'm using Richfaces 4, it might be useful information.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Stefan

Comment: can you please post your cancel button xhtml and flow definition?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to Spring Webflows or Richfaces, but to the standard JSF lifecycle that handles every request to the server.

This cycle consists of several phases (google "jsf lifecycle" for plenty of illustrations and explanations). One of them is processing all validators. If validation fails, the cycle will be aborted and a response (current page + messages) is sent. The method invocation phase, which would process your cancel button, will not be reached.

When adding `immediate=true` to the button it will move the processing of this button to the process validations phase, hence it will be called *before* processing the validation failure events (and thus the re-rendering of the page).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding immediate="true" to your Cancel button XHTML